# Error accessing keys in Python dictionary

Tags: python

I'm doing a request with the following data body and when I try to access `users["primary"]` it errors out. printing the value for the `users` key gives me `['secondaryIds', 'primary']` which is weird. Why is this an array rather than a dictionary.

```
data = {
    "users": {
        "primary": "a",
        "secondaryIds": ["b", "c", "a"]
    }
}

r = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

In my server code, before I get into the function where I'm trying to unpack the data, I do

```
body = event["body"]
parameters = urllib.parse.parse_qs(body)
users = parameters["users"]

update_users(users) // right now this function just prints `users` and returns a 200
```

Confused as to what's going on here and would love a little help. Thanks!

Comment: There is no code here which tries to access `users["primary"]`.  Please show us the actual code that has an error.

Comment: Also, saying "it errors out" doesn't really help.  Please post the actual full error message.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't throw an actual error since I'm just returning a 200 for now. It just doesn't access the key like I'd expect

Comment: Are you using any framework on the server? Doesn't it have code to parse the body automatically?

Comment: Print out or use a debugger and check the shape of `users`.

Comment: @solarc will do an update my original post in a sec

Comment: Printing the shape of the data gives me `{'users': ['secondaryIds', 'primary']}`. I was expecting a nested dict under the users key, not an array of two strings

Comment: I believe the issue is that you are trying to parse the request body as a query string. Had you passed the data dict in the params= keyword arg of requests.post() that might have worked (perhaps URL or json encoded) but isn't really the right way to post and parse this type of data. As @Barmar noted this is typically something the web server does for you...can you show the type and value of event and event["body"]?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're setting

```
users = data['users']
```

that is a correctly raised `NameError`.

I think you want `data['users']['primary']`

---

Based on the updates to your question, this is likely happening because you're trying to parse a dictionary as a querystring. If you omit the line

```
parameters = urllib.parse.parse_qs(body)
```

you should be able to access the `users` list with

```
body['users']
```

or with

```
json.loads(body)['user']
```

I'm unclear on how your `event` returns the request body (if it parses it as json before returning or not)

Comment: It's more likely a `NameError` than a `KeyError` at the moment.

Comment: @ZackShapiro I've updated my answer based on your updates, let me know if that helps